# Range filter in Elastic search not providing expected results

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I am using php elastica lib to fetch data. The issue is, it finds the result till range 9.9 (float value) and doesn't accept two digit number (i.e 10 and above). I want to fetch those values too.

The code written below is the array which is fetching wrong results:

```
[filters] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [range] => Array
                    (
                        [Carat] => Array
                            (
                                [lte] => 9.9
                                [gte] => 2.93
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: I didnt gey your question. Your query only searches results under 9.9 so what is the problem actually?

Comment: You have "lte" 9.9. "lte" stands for "less than (or) equal" in most contexts. Why do you believe it should give results of 10 or above?

Comment: this is just an example, if i write 10 or above instead of 9.9 it wont work.